# Как определить кнопку какого пункта ListView мы нажали?

Tags: android, listview

Как определить кнопку какого пункта `ListView` мы нажали?

В каждом пункте списка есть `TextView` и 2 кнопки. Вторая из них Удалить. по её нажатию нужно удалить пункт списка...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
                names.length);
        Map<String, Object> m;
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, names[i]);
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_BUTTON, button[i]);
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_BUTTON2, button2[0]);
            data.add(m);
        }
        String[] from = { ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, ATTRIBUTE_NAME_BUTTON,
                ATTRIBUTE_NAME_BUTTON2 };
        // массив ID View-компонентов, в которые будут вставлять данные
        int[] to = { R.id.text1, R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2 };
        SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.my_list_item,
                from, to);
        lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
        lvMain.setAdapter(sAdapter);


    }
```

То есть надо написать метод :

```
 public void onButtonClick(View v){
       ????  a = ???
        data.remove(a.position);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался уже:

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    final int postion = lvMain.getPositionForView(v);
    data.remove(postion);
    sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Это костыль. Если вы хотите вешать слушатели на внутренние элементы разметки списка, то создайте свой адаптер и вешайте слушатели там, в методе onGetView. А ещё лучше перепишите на RecyclerView, т.к. ListView устарел.